# minipage wrapping tabularx overfull box

Tags: minipage, tabularx, warnings

1. The line `Zur Erläuterung der...` should introduce the following list. This produces an underfull hbox and I just can't get rid of it.
2. To keep the content together on one page I found the solution in some post to wrap everything into a minipage.Is this the right procedure? Because this causes overfull boxes of about `104pt`.
3. The same for the tabular inside. It actually looks like expected, but the warnings drive me crazy...

I noticed the problem with the minipages a few times in my doc already. And I try to work with linewidth always... One thing to add before: I globally set no indent in my preamble already. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[
paper=a4,
parskip=half*   %vertikaler Abstand nach Absätzen
]{scrreprt}

\tolerance=2000
\emergencystretch=1em
\hfuzz=2pt
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    Zur Erläuterung der Vorgehensweise definiert Bechmann die folgenden Variablen:

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{.35\linewidth}X}
        $K_1,K_2,\dots,K_n$ & die n Kriterien, bezüglich der bewertet werden soll.\\
        $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_m$ & die m verschiedenen Alternativen, die bewertet werden sollen.\\
        $g_1,g_2,\dots,g_n$ & Gewichte der Kriterien\\
        $k_{ij}$ $i=1,\dots,n$ $j=1,\dots,m$ & Zielertrag des i-ten Kriteriums bezüglich der j-ten Alternative\\
        $e_{ij}$ $i=1,\dots,n$ $j=1,\dots,m$ & Zielerfüllungsgrad des i-ten Kriteriums\\
        $N_{ij}$ $i=1,\dots,n$ $j=1,\dots,m$ & Teilnutzwert des i-ten Kriteriums bezüglich der j-ten Alternative\\
        $N_j$ $j=1,\dots,m$ & Nutzwert der j-ten Alternative\\
    \end{tabularx}

    \vskip .5em
    es gilt dabei $N_{ij}=g_i*e_{ij}$ \\ und $N_j=N_{1j}+N_{2j}+\dots+N_{nj}=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}N_{ij}$
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

BTW: in case of any relevance: I use TexStudio 2.10.6 and MikTeX 2.9

[image: This is the warning]

Comment: why do you use \\ before  `tabularx` ?

Comment: it was an attempt to prevent latex of stretching this few words on two lines... Do you know a more elegant way? =)

Comment: @Eric: You should provide the document around this table, i.e. at least the compilable version that has this table.

Comment: If add before `\begin{minipage}` command `\noindent`, the overfull mesage will disappear.

Comment: @Zarko unfortunately this is not the case. But the hint with the table wrap worked already.

Comment: I agree with @Zarko. `table` is special environment it's for floats things

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. `\noindent` can't fix the issue and the warnings disappear in case of a table environment. Does anyone has an explanation therefore? I'll complement my code above asap.

Comment: Code is updated: I figured out that it is attributed to `parskip=half*`.

Comment: is there a way to keep this setting and fix the overfull boxes?

Comment: using `\displaystyle` in the middle of an equation is very weird, it means the lhs is set as inline math and the whole of the right hand side is set as display,

Comment: note that your first sentence has the  correct solution. this is a _list_ and would be better set as such and not use tabular (and definitely not tabularx) at all here,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for your help! I adapted the `\displaystyle` hint. The problem with the list is that I need two columns which I seperately want to adjust in their width. Would you use a list in this case anyway? If yes I would appreciate an example of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often the described symptoms are caused by the parskip indent. In this obvious case it can easily be solved by setting either locally `\noindent` before the respective paragraph or in a general manner as global definition by `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`.

In my specific case the issue was produced by the document class option `parskip=half*` of the **KOMA-Script**. I noticed this as I commented the parksip=half* out and found the solution on `page 71` of the **KOMA-Script** manual.

> half*
>
> > half a line vertical space between paragraphs; there must be at least a quarter of a line free space at the end of a paragraph

The problem was the second condition: "at least a quarter of a line free space at the end of a pargraph".

> half-
>
> > one line vertical space between paragraphs

Therefore I switched to the `half-` command to keep the vertical space and get rid of the overfull boxes.

I hope this helps others with the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in my comment, you have problem with `\parindent`. Your minipage widt with of `\textwidth` doesn't start at left text border bit after `parindent` and consequently for its amount protrude right text border caused warning `Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--31`. I f you add before `begin{minipage}˛` a command `\noindent` or set `\parindent` to zero, this warning disappear:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
Zur Erläuterung der Vorgehensweise definiert Bechmann die folgenden Variablen:

\vspace{\baselineskip}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
$K_1,K_2,\dots,K_n$ & die $n$ Kriterien, bezüglich der bewertet werden soll.\\
$A_1,A_2,\dots,A_m$ & die $m$ verschiedenen Alternativen, die bewertet werden sollen.\\
$g_1,g_2,\dots,g_n$ & Gewichte der Kriterien\\
$k_{ij}$ $i=1,\dots,n$ $j=1,\dots,m$
                    & Zielertrag des $i$-ten Kriteriums bezüglich der j-ten Alternative\\
$e_{ij}$ $i=1,\dots,n$ $j=1,\dots,m$
                    & Zielerfüllungsgrad des $i$-ten Kriteriums\\
$N_{ij}$ $i=1,\dots,n$ $j=1,\dots,m$
                    & Teilnutzwert des $i$-ten Kriteriums bezüglich der $j$-ten Alternative\\
$N_j$ $j=1,\dots,m$ & Nutzwert der $j$-ten Alternative\\
    \end{tabularx}

\vskip .5\baselineskip
es gilt dabei $N_{ij}=g_i*e_{ij}$  

und $N_j=N_{1j}+N_{2j}+\dots+N_{nj}=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}N_{ij}$
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** I corrected some typing error in given MWE. Also let be noted: if you like to start the table content of the first column at left border of mini page, than you should do the following

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lX}
```

Proposed solution also works with your document class (added at completing of your MWE: `\documentclass[paper=a4,parskip=half*]{scrreprt}`

**Edit (2):** Here is image of your minipage generated with your MWE.

[image]

I also add missing part of your example (I'm sorry for this)

Comment: also this code still produces overfull boxes...

Comment: No. I didn't find anything in .log file. For test erase old .aux and .log file and then compile my code again. You will not find any warning.

Comment: I updated my code into a MWE and noticed that it is attributed to the parskip=half* setting. But is there a solution to keep the setting and fix the prob?

Comment: I compile your MWE. It doesn't give any warning about overfull boxes. However, I get warning about babel (in my system since I haven't installed babel for "ngerman"), but his is not a question, isn't it?

Comment: this is weired... I deleted my log and aux files and compiled it again with an overfull box. Watch the picture I inserted above.

Comment: I can't reproduce your image with your code. See last edit of my answer. I don't know, what is going wrong at you. Really weird.

Answer (score 1):

Please include full minimal working examples including the relevant packages you use.

Your code produces both an underfull and overfull box. I don't think creating a minipage is really helping here. I can recommend wrapping the `\tabularx{}` environment into a `\table{}` environment which in your example doesn't produce any overfull boxes. Also the geometry package helps if you want to change the width of your page.

> ```
>   \documentclass{article}
>   \usepackage[top=4cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=4cm]{geometry}
>   \usepackage{tabularx}
>   \begin{document}
>      \begin{table}
>           Zur Erläuterung der Vorgehensweise definiert Bechmann die folgenden Variablen: \\[0.5cm]
>      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{.35\linewidth}X}
>           $K_1,K_2,\dots,K_n$ & die n Kriterien, bezüglich der bewertet werden soll.\\
>           $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_m$ & die m verschiedenen Alternativen, die bewertet werden sollen.\\
>           $g_1,g_2,\dots,g_n$ & Gewichte der Kriterien\\
>           $k_{ij}$ $i=1,\dots,n$ $j=1,\dots,m$ & Zielertrag des i-ten Kriteriums bezüglich der j-ten Alternative\\
>           $e_{ij}$ $i=1,\dots,n$ $j=1,\dots,m$ & Zielerfüllungsgrad des i-ten Kriteriums\\
>           $N_{ij}$ $i=1,\dots,n$ $j=1,\dots,m$ & Teilnutzwert des i-ten Kriteriums bezüglich der j-ten Alternative\\
>           $N_j$ $j=1,\dots,m$ & Nutzwert der j-ten Alternative\\
>      \end{tabularx}
>          \vskip .5em
>      es gilt dabei $N_{ij}=g_i*e_{ij}$ und $N_j=N_{1j}+N_{2j}+\dots+N_{nj}=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}N_{ij}$
>     \end{table}
> \end{document}
> ```

**Edit:** Turns out the `\table{}` wrap doesn't really fix the overfull hbox. Rather the geometry package fixed it by broaden the sitewidth which might not be a suitable solution. However overfull hboxs could usually be fixed by forced hypothenation using `\-` in the first sentence of the given example.

Comment: when I add a table environment for some reason the overfull-box warning disappears... why this doesn't really fix the problem?

Comment: It does fix it by using the package mentioned in my answer. The answers from the other guys are more suitable, check them out.

Answer (score 1):

1) `\noindent\begin{minipage}`

2) no need to `\\` befor `tabularx` if necessary

`\makebox[\linewidth]{Zur Erläuterung der Vorgehensweise definiert Bechmann die folgenden Variablen:}`

3) `p{.3\linewidth}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\makebox[\linewidth]{Zur Erläuterung der Vorgehensweise definiert Bechmann die folgenden Variablen:}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{.3\linewidth}X}
        $K_1,K_2,\dots,K_n$ & die n Kriterien, bezüglich der bewertet werden soll.\\
        $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_m$ & die m verschiedenen Alternativen, die bewertet werden sollen.\\
        $g_1,g_2,\dots,g_n$ & Gewichte der Kriterien\\
        $k_{ij}$ $i=1,\dots,n$ $j=1,\dots,m$ & Zielertrag des i-ten Kriteriums bezüglich der j-ten Alternative\\
        $e_{ij}$ $i=1,\dots,n$ $j=1,\dots,m$ & Zielerfüllungsgrad des i-ten Kriteriums\\
        $N_{ij}$ $i=1,\dots,n$ $j=1,\dots,m$ & Teilnutzwert des i-ten Kriteriums bezüglich der j-ten Alternative\\
        $N_j$ $j=1,\dots,m$ & Nutzwert der j-ten Alternative\\
    \end{tabularx}

    \vskip .5em
    es gilt dabei $N_{ij}=g_i*e_{ij}$ \\ und $N_j=N_{1j}+N_{2j}+\dots+N_{nj}=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}N_{ij}$
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thx, but this code still produces overfull boxes for me

Comment: I updated my code above and still having trouble with the overfull boxes...